I want to add Quill-Cursors to Ngx-Quill for collaborative real-time editor
I tried using ngx-Quill with websocket (socket.io) for real-time text editing which works but i want to add a cursor for each user, i tried using quill-cursors package but the documentation is using normal quill package and not ngx-quill
Here's my component.ts
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { WebSocketService } from '../../websocket.service';
import { QuillConfig } from '../../quill-config';

import Quill from 'quill';
import QuillCursors from 'quill-cursors';
import { QuillEditorComponent } from 'ngx-quill';

Quill.register('modules/cursors', QuillCursors);

const quill = new Quill('#quillEditor', {
  modules: {
    cursors: true,
  }
});

@Component({
  selector: 'app-document-editor',
  templateUrl: './document-editor.component.html',
  styleUrl: './document-editor.component.scss'
})
export class DocumentEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(QuillEditorComponent, { static: true }) editor!: QuillEditorComponent;

  private isUpdating = false;
  private docId!: string;
  private subscription!: Subscription;

  docContent=""
  currentCursor=0

  editorConfig = {
    toolbar: QuillConfig,
    clipboard: {
      matchVisual: false,
    }
  };

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private wsService: WebSocketService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.docId = params['id'];

      this.wsService.connect(this.docId);

      this.subscription = this.wsService.messages.subscribe((message: any) => {
        if (message && !this.isUpdating) {
          this.isUpdating = true;
          this.docContent = message;
          this.isUpdating = false;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const quill = this.editor.quillEditor;
    const cursors = quill.getModule('cursors');

    quill.on('selection-change', (range: any) => {
      if (range) {
        this.currentCursor = range.index;
        // Send cursor position to WebSocket server
        this.wsService.sendMessage(JSON.stringify({ cursor: this.currentCursor }));
      }
    });

    // Listen for cursor positions from other users
    this.wsService.messages.subscribe((message: any) => {
      if (message.cursor) {
        cursors.createCursor('other-user', 'Other User', 'blue');
        cursors.moveCursor('other-user', { index: message.cursor, length: 0 });
      }
    });
  }

  onContentChanged(event: any): void {
    if (!this.isUpdating) {
      //const content = JSON.stringify(this.editor.quillEditor.getContents());
      this.wsService.sendMessage(this.docContent);
    }
  }

  onSelectionChanged(event: any){
    this.currentCursor = event.range.index
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.wsService.disconnect();
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}

And this is the html file
<div>
  <quill-editor 
    id="quillEditor"
    [(ngModel)]="docContent" 
    [modules]="editorConfig"
    (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)"
    (onSelectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
  ></quill-editor>
</div>

my websocket service
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
  private socket!: Socket;
  private messagesSubject$ = new Subject<any>();
  public messages = this.messagesSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public connect(docId: string): void {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');

    this.socket.emit('joinDocument', docId);

    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to WebSocket server');
    });

    this.socket.on('message', (message: any) => {
      this.messagesSubject$.next(message);
    });

    this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
    });
  }

  public sendMessage(message: string): void {
    this.socket.emit('message', message);
  }

  public disconnect(): void {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
}

and finally my basic node server
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// MongoDB connection
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/documents';

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));

const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  docId: String,
  content: String
});

const Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema);

const app = express();

// Allow all CORS requests
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
});

const documentRooms = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New client connected');

  socket.on('joinDocument', async (docId) => {
    socket.join(docId);
    documentRooms[socket.id] = docId;

    // Fetch the document content from the database and send it to the client
    const document = await Document.findOne({ docId });
    if (document) {
      socket.emit('message', document.content);
    }
  });

  socket.on('message', async (data) => {
    const docId = documentRooms[socket.id];
    io.to(docId).emit('message', data);

    // Save the document content to the database
    await Document.findOneAndUpdate(
      { docId },
      { content: data },
      { upsert: true }
    );
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const docId = documentRooms[socket.id];
    if (docId) {
      socket.leave(docId);
      delete documentRooms[socket.id];
    }
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(Server running on port ${PORT}));

the websocket works fine with just a small problem that the receiver cursor is always reset but the current writer can keep writing normally, and the data is updated in real-time
i want to add all current users cursor in real time, for now i can use a random id or websocket client id but later i will add user authentication and username.
Current approach
I tried adding quill cursor like this
import Quill from 'quill';
import QuillCursors from 'quill-cursors';
import { QuillEditorComponent } from 'ngx-quill';

Quill.register('modules/cursors', QuillCursors);

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const quill = this.editor.quillEditor;
    const cursors = quill.getModule('cursors');

    quill.on('selection-change', (range: any) => {
      if (range) {
        this.currentCursor = range.index;
        console.log(range)
        this.wsService.sendMessage(JSON.stringify({ cursor: this.currentCursor }));
      }
    });

    // Listen for cursor positions from other users
    this.wsService.messages.subscribe((message: any) => {
      if (message.cursor) {
        this.updateCursor(message.cursor);
      }
    });
  }

but got this error and the data no longer transmit to websocket
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getModule')
    at _DocumentEditorComponent.ngAfterViewInit (document-editor.component.ts:60:27)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:5136:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:5163:13)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:5118:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:5068:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12862:21)
    at detectChangesInView$1 (core.mjs:13015:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:12978:5)
    at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12935:13)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12815:9)

chunk-SFFCLR5V.js?v=760c53bf:56 quill Cannot import modules/modules. Are you sure it was registered?

I also tried this
QuillModule.forRoot({
      customModules: [{
        implementation: QuillCursors,
        path: 'modules/cursors'
      }]
    })

but still the same error
